# Angularstrap typeaheads pop up select list bug

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, angular-strap

I'm not sure whether this is a bug, so for the angular strap, when I input something not in the select list, when I click away and click it again, the select list will pop up. However, if I choose the item in the select list and click away and click back, the select list won't show up. Is there any solution to make the select list show up?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Icon</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-min-length="0" data-html="1" data-auto-select="true" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="icon for icon in icons" placeholder="Enter icon" bs-typeahead>
</div>
```

The plunker is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NwFqsdUWcSi5RyKOAMkt?p=preview

So I want the function that when I input Alaska in the Icon input and select Alaska from select list, when I click away and click back the select list will show up. Thanks.

update:

```
var isVisible = typeahead.$isVisible();
isVisible && typeahead.update(values);
// Do not re-queue an update if a correct value has been selected
if(values.length === 1 && values[0].value === newValue) return;
!isVisible && typeahead.update(values);
// Queue a new rendering that will leverage collection loading
controller.$render();
```

The angular strap code seems don't allow re-queue the selected value. So for my question, if I us ng-blur to trigger an function to replace the object, and the problem is fixed. I'm not sure why it implemented like this.

Comment: which browser are you using? because i was not able to reproduce it

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Both in chrome and ie11. I updated some code in angular strap for reference. It seems that it don't allow the re-queue the update.

Comment: I am running into the same issue both on Chrome and Firefox. Were you able to find a solution?